# Number Format Not working properly in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a problem with this code here. It recognizes both `12/05/2020` and `2020/05/12` as not `dd/mm/yyyy`, any solution?

```
Sub checkDateFormat()
    Call declareVars
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim colStartCell As Range
    Dim colEndCell As Range
    Dim cNum As Integer
    Dim dateFormat As String
    Dim n As Integer
    n = 0
    For Each Cell In g_validationRange
        If 0 < InStr(UCase(Cell), UCase(C_CHECKDATE_KW)) Then
            cNum = Cell.Column
            Set colStartCell = Cells(g_firstDataRangeRow, cNum)
            'MsgBox colStartCell.Address
            Set colEndCell = Cells(g_dataLastRowNum, cNum)
            'MsgBox colEndCell.Address
            Set rng = Range(colStartCell, colEndCell)
            cellArray = splitArray(Cell)
            Set cellCollection = validationCheck(cellArray, C_CHECKDATE_KW)
            dateFormat = cellCollection(1)
            n = 0

            For Each repcell In rng
                reqDate = CDate(repcell.Value)
                'MsgBox collContains(cellCollection, repcell.Value)
                    If repcell.NumberFormat <> dateFormat Then
                        n = n + 1
                        repcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                    End If
            Next repcell
        End If
    Next Cell
    If n <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please use the dd/mm/yyyy  date format in " & n & " cells highlighted under " & Cells(g_attrFirstRowNum, cNum)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is `12/05/2020` December 5th, or May 12th?

Comment: We will assume it as 12th May, no matter even if it had to be 5th December for the user who enters the date. There id no mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: You might need a better way to input/validate dates ... checking the `.NumberFormat` seems to be a weak validation, especially if you have users in different locales.

Comment: What is the code that you are using to define `dateFormat`?

Comment: It returns DD/MM/YYYY. That function is perfect because I have used it in some of my other modules too, and it is totally fine. the problem lies in if statement.

Comment: In default mode, in VBA, `DD/MM/YYYY` <> `dd/mm/yyyy`. Text comparisons are case sensitive.  If you put a break point at the `If` statement, and then, in the immediate window, type `?repcell.NumberFormat` and also `?dateFormat`, what is returned?